# Wordpress - Unsure why sidebars have become inactive in my child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Two custom sidebars have become inactive in my theme, and I have no idea why, or how to fix it. I am using a child theme based on twentyseventeen. They worked fine previously.

Below is the code that registers the sidebars and adds them to the front page template. The output markup confirms that the correct template file is being used.

[image]

**theme-functions.php**

```
function twentyseventeenchild_widgets_init() {
  register_sidebar(
    array(
      'name'          => __( 'Home Sidebar', 'twentyseventeenchild' ),
      'id'            => 'sidebar-4',
      'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar on the homne page.', 'twentyseventeenchild' ),
      'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
      'after_widget'  => '</section>',
      'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
      'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    )
  );
  register_sidebar(
    array(
      'name'          => __( 'Home pano', 'twentyseventeenchild' ),
      'id'            => 'home-pano',
      'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear above the homepage content.', 'twentyseventeenchild' ),
      
    )
  );
}
```

**front-page.php**

```
<aside id="home-pano" class="widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Home pano', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home-pano' ); ?>
</aside>

<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Home Sidebar', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ); ?>
</aside>
```

**Output on home page**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the following line at the bottom of the file:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyseventeenchild_widgets_init' );
```